# Python extract data from file and write to another

Tags: python, file-io

I'm new in python and need help.
I have a file and want to extract text to another file.

The input file looks like this:

```
<Datei Kennung="4bc78" Titel="Morgen 1" Bereich="I847YP"> Morgen 1

Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.

</Datei>
<Datei Kennung="469" Titel="Trop Hall W " Bereich="izr"> Trop Hall W

Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.    


</Datei>
```

For the first area in my file i need as output the file Morgen 1.txt
which contains this:

```
Morgen 1

Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.
Here is text, contains numbers and text.
```

I got from other user this code:

```
import re
REG_PARSE=re.compile(r'<Datei[^>]*Titel="\s*([^"]*?)\s*"[^>]*>\s*\1\s*(.*?</Datei>',re.dotall)
with open(filename) as infile:
for outfilename, text = REG_PARSE.finditer(infile.read()):
    with open('%s.txt'%outfilename,'w') as outf:
        outf.write(text)
```

but it does not work

Comment: use [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/) to read the infile, as it seems to be in XML format. Then use normal [file-io](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to write to another file. Also, what have you tried so far??

Comment: Dude, please edit your question instead of posting a comment with code

Comment: I've added your code to your OP as best as I could. Please verify that it's correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out... it works...

```
fp = open("data.txt", "r")
data = fp.read();

data = data.split(">");

i = 0;

while True:
    filename = data[i].split('" ')[1].split('"')[1]
    text = data[i+1].split('<')[0].strip()

    fp1 = open(filename + ".txt", "w")
    fp1.write(text)
    fp1.close()

    i += 2
    if i >= (len(data) - 1):
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish Merry Xmas to you and family.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc  = minidom.parse('/path/to/file')
items   = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Datei') 

for s in items:
    if s.attributes['Titel'].value == "Morgen 1":
        with open("Morgen 1.txt", "w") as fileOutput:
            listLines = [   line.strip()
                            for line in s.firstChild.nodeValue.strip().split("\n")
                            if line.strip()
                            ]

            fileOutput.write("\n".join(listLines))
            break
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a quick-and-dirty way to do this, without using xml (recommended), this will do the job:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    found = False
    outfile = open("Morgen 1.txt", 'w')
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("<Datei") and 'Titel="Morgen 1"' in line:
            found = True
        elif line.startswith("</Datei"):
            found = False
        if found:
            if not line.startswith("<Datei"):
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the other code works perfectly for me. I wish to you and family Merry Xmas.